# Table /input fields are not shown

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF-File. Wanna take a name during the input field... But the field ist not showing after running the file. I can see only WHATS YOUR NAME in the browser.

Thx and greetings :)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>index 2</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        Whats your Name?<br/>
        <h:inputText value="#(user.name)"/>
        <h:commandButton action="greet" value="GO"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to be sure, what does 'view-source' in the browser show you? Something identical to the xhtml above?

Comment: I think you are using the EL expression in an wrong way, instead of `#(user.name)` use `#{user.name}`

Comment: Hi guys....thx for the quick response...@Kukeltje the browser shows me only "What your name?"...not more

Comment: @JorgeCampos doesnt working with "{" instead of "("....but thx for the idea

Comment: What does your  web.xml  look like ? please add it to the question.

Comment: @estebanrincon Thx for your response. I added the web.xml now

Comment: @Bartolomeo: I said VIEW SOURCE, not the result of rendering the page itself... please read better next time what comments are made. But BalusC already marked it as a duplicate since he thinks, just like I do, you have indeed a problem mentioned in the duplicate

Comment: @Kukeltje sry my mistake, I read the existing question after Balus marked it....I changed the web.xml file... i getting a new error now. Thx for your help and time

Comment: You should not reuse an old question for a new question. Ask a new question for a new question.